# How to deploy a vuejs project to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on this project locally https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot but now that it is finished, I would like to push it to heroku. the problem is telling heroku to start the app.

In the heroku example, the demo server runs after picking up the info from `Procfile` with contains this data

```
web: node index.js
```

But in my vuejs project, there is no index.js that servers the content.

I only have the main entry point which is `index.html` and the procfile doesn't work with HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the git repo, I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @bhansa Another good one is [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org/). I actually moved from CoPilot to quasar last month and haven't regretted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your package.json file to let heroku know about the packages, for example if you are using **express** to serve your files:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "npm install express"
 }
 // "start": "node server.js" (executing server.js) during start
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(port)
console.log('server started ' + port)
```

Don't forget to **build**.

Look here to read more about build conf: [Customizing build process - Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)

You can also install the http-server globally like this if that is a option:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

and update the Procfile to add the configuration as mentioned in above answers.

> Just to know:

- **npm install** will install both "dependencies" and "devDependencies"
- npm install --**production** will only install "dependencies"
- npm install --**dev** will only install "devDependencies"

Answer (score 8):

You also need to define a small static server to serve your `index.html` file.
A simple example setup would be with `http-server`:

```
npm install -S http-server
```

And your `Procfile` becomes:

```
web: http-server ./ -p $PORT
```

Comment: Hmm,  I tried your answer and I get ` 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`  Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Current answer could not solve the problem, so I a putting a bounty

Comment: Did you install `http-server` correctly? Does it show up under `dependencies` in your package.json file? Also, can you run the command `http-server ./ -p 8080` locally on your own machine?

Comment: Yes, everything is installed correctly. I am getting `error module semver` not found... i can't tell what the issue is

Comment: Does it run locally? Could you also post your Node and npm versions? Also, maybe this npm issue is related https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15558

Answer (score 2):

Using `http-server`. but the package is not installed globally, so you will have to use the full path to it like so:

`web: ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server ./ -p $PORT`